# Keycloak IDP initiated logout SAML

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, keycloak

I have one SP and one IDP using Keycloak.
I'm using SAML protocol and I can successfully login and logout when the request is initiated by the SP.

But when connected as an admin in Keycloak I logout an user from his session no request are sent to the SP. 
The session is indeed terminated on the IDP side but not on the SP side.
Because of that the user on the SP can still use the application.

I can't see any option in client configuration for that.

Has anyone made IDP initiated log out in SAML works with keycloak ?
Could you give me some directions ?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

After some other research this is not a feature of Keycloak.

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/2.5/server_admin/topics/sessions/administering.html

Quoting the docs

> Only certain clients are notified of this logout event, specifically clients that are using the Keycloak OIDC client adapter. Other client types (i.e. SAML) will not receive a backchannel logout request.

Comment: This seems not up-to-date anymore.

Comment: @BrunoJCM Why ? see https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#logout-all-limitations

Comment: That link is now broken, @André, maybe it's https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#limitations-of-the-code-logout-all-code-operation now. But in that case this refers to the "Logout all" button in the Keycloak Admin Console and may not apply to logouts in general.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issues using keycloak saml broker. It turned out that enabling back-channel logout (disabling front-channel logout) in keycloak client configuration solved my problem.

I am using 4.8.0.Final